# Find Line with specific Angle to another Line

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

> Given any line in 3 dimensional space
>
> $$A: \vec{X} = \vec{O} + \lambda \vec{D}$$
>
> and any angle $\phi$, I want to find another line $B$ which fullfills the following criteria:
>
> 1. it should intersect with line $A$ at any point
> 2. $\dfrac{A_\vec{D} \cdot B_\vec{D}}{|A_\vec{D}| \times |B_\vec{D}|} = cos(\phi)$, therefore the angle between line $A$ and $B$ should equal $\phi$.

I am able to do this in 2 dimensions, where applying a rotation matrix simply solves the probem. But I can't solve it in 3 dimensions because the rotation matrix consists of two components (when looking at the angles the matrix is built of) and one is depending on the other when aiming for a specific angle.

Can you please elaborate on how to compute any $B$? The equation *may* require another angle $\gamma$ that defines the banking of the new line on the other.

Comment: There are $\infty$ such lines.

Comment: @exploringnet: I know. Please read my last sentence: `The equation may require another angle γ that defines the banking of the new line on the other.`

Comment: In point **2**, are you trying to denote multiplication with the $\times$ symbol?  I recommend using $\cdot$ (`\cdot`) when dealing with vectors so the symbol isn't confused with the cross product.  Also for point 2, but on the RHS: Shouldn't that be $\cos(\phi)$, not $\phi$?

Comment: 1) It should be the multiplication symbol, $|A_\vec{D}|$ is a single number. (The length of the vector $\vec{D}$). What symbol should I prefer? 2) Oh yes, you are right! Thanks

Comment: @exploringnet You have just removed my addition with $cos(\phi)$ with your edit. Could you please add it? **Edit: Nevermind, did already**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to pick some vector $\vec C$ not along $\vec D$.  Then find $\vec E = \vec C \times \vec D$ which will be perpendicular to $\vec D$.  Find unit vectors $\hat D$ and $\hat E$.  Finally your vector is $\vec F=\cos \phi \hat D + \sin \phi \hat E$ and the line is $\vec O+ \lambda \vec F$